# Find an efficient way of searching in nested python lists

Tags: python, excel

I am very new to this forum and am basically a Network Engineer learning Python to automate some tasks and make my work more efficient. Well, straight to the point. I have a big excel workbook of 4 sheets with around 50K rows in each sheet. After learning for couple of weeks and extensive search I was able to load the whole excel cell values in a nested list e.g.

```
list [sheet_index][row_index][column_index].
```

Now after getting the inputs, next part is manipulation of those data. My task is to find specific column value from each row and search in the entire workbook and if found, corresponding data from a different column should be written in line with the original searched object.

My method is like below:

> Getting the cell values in a big list (as I mentioned earlier)
>   flatten that list in a different variable as a one dimensional list.
>   in a loop, get the specific value from a row (fixed column) and search in entire one-dimensional list, if found, write the corresponding value in a different excel file.

So far, this method is working fine with a extra long delay which was the motivation for drifting from Excel VBA program to Python. So, I am here to ask the experts if theres something very basic I am missing. Here is the code below:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
from compiler.ast import flatten

datafile = 'Peering_DB.xls'
# Data Read Function Definition
def main(datafile):
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(datafile)
wwb =  copy(wb)
data = [[[wb.sheet_by_index(i).cell_value(r, col)
    for col in range(wb.sheet_by_index(i).ncols)]
        for r in range(wb.sheet_by_index(i).nrows)]
            for i in range(0,4)]

data1 = flatten(data)

k = 2
x = 0

while x < 4:
    r = wb.sheet_by_index(x).nrows
    A = data[x][k][1]
    B = data[x][k][2]
    counter = 4
    loc = [loc for (loc , e ) in enumerate(data1) if e == A]
    if len(loc) != 1:
        for n in range(len(loc)):
            if  data1[loc[n] + 1] != B:
                wwb.get_sheet(x).write(k,counter,data1[loc[n] + 1])
                counter = counter + 1
    else:
        wwb.get_sheet(x).write(k,counter,"No Backup")

    k = k + 1

    if  k == r - 1  and x < 3:
        print 'Page number ', x , 'Completed'
        x = x + 1
        k = 2
    elif k == r and x == 3:
        print "Operation Completed Successfully"
        break


wwb.save('Peering_output.xls')
```

main(datafile)

Comment: A simple change of the code has improved its performance from 6hours tp 25mins!! Thought, this information might be useful to the other novice programmer like me out there. The change was to search the data inside a variable and if found, writing it in the variable itself by extending its element. then finally, that variable is used to write the excel. Simple trick but I was so dumb to pick it up. And I am starting to love python!